# Devise remember me not storing cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've set up a simple sample app that uses devise for user authentication.

When I select the rember me checkbox on login I get the following in the console:

> Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"commit"=>"Sign in", "authenticity_token"=>"Vm+2aWEmCRnnjdXAOpXdI5dGChUKlEcmfGNXNoGUkwc=", "utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"1", "password"
>   =>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"test@example.com"}}
>     ←[1m←[35mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test@example.com' LIMIT 1
>     ←[1m←[36mAREL (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mUPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2011-10-06 21:36:46.439511', "updated_at" = '2011-10-06 21:43:59.298269', "sign_in_coun
>   t" = 15, "current_sign_in_at" = '2011-10-06 21:43:59.297269' WHERE "users"."id" = 1←[0m

I have the following in my Posts controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

However, when I close the browser and open it again I am forced to login again before I can view posts. It doesn't seem that the cookie is being stored. I found the following cookie in firefox for my page:

Cookie Name: remember_user_token
Expires: at end of session

Is this the cookie thats supposed to be stored and expire at a future date but instead expires at the end of session? Can someone verify this?

I've tried both commenting and uncommenting `config.remember_for = 2.weeks` in devise.rb to different settings and nothing seems to fix the problem.

My User.rb file looks like this:

> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
>           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
>
> # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
>
> attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
>
> end

Comment: Silly question. Did you restart your server after uncommenting `config.remember_for = 2.weeks`?

Comment: Yes, I did janders, good point though. Didn't change anything for me

Comment: I've not used the remember me function in awhile due to security concerns in my company. I'll try to play around with it this weekend and see if I can figure something out.

Comment: I have found that when I deploy this code to my linux host it works fine. I'm developing on a Windows 7 PC and it does not work there.

Comment: I see. You will find that a lot of the Ruby gems will not work with Windows.

Comment: In my case, it was because it was expecting secure cookies.