# Devise 'remember me' to prevent login between sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

(I've seen the other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680913/devise-remember-me-not-storing-cookie), and I've followed the documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Omniauthable,-sign-out-action-and-rememberable), but it still doesn't work)

Currently users have to sign in every time they close the browser. I want them to be kept logged in indefinitely.

I tried using the Devise 'remember me' function, but it doesn't seem to work.

I do see a cookie created, called 'remember_user_token', but this doesn't seem to have any effect on the login.

All my config.remember_for settings are disabled

What am I doing wrong?

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  include Devise::Controllers::Rememberable

    def create
      omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      authentication = omniauth['uid'].present? ? Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid']) : nil
      ...
      respond @user
    end

    def respond(user)
      user.remember_me = true
      sign_in user, event: :authentication
      remember_me(user)
    end
    ...
end
```

Comment: i don't understand what you are asking for

Comment: @phoet thanks! is it clearer now?